# javascript ioredis : takes 3s to push an array of 150K objects

Tags: javascript, caching, redis

I'm quite surprised how slow is ioredis to push an array of 150K objects  (very simple objects). This is on my windows10 laptop, not on a remote machine. Using nodejs as back end and windows redis-cli  3.2.100

Have a singlekey and a single array made of this 150K objects

Below is the type of oject I want to push in Redis and the simple command I used to do it.

Is there a way to optimize this ?

```
const redisStore:redis.Redis = new redis();

interface IPrepareSearchEntity {
    type: string;
    searchkey: string;
    key: string;
    preview: TPreview
}

interface TPreview{
    email:string;
    country:string;
    url:string;
}

const writeToCache = async (redisStore: Redis, key:string, array:TPreview[]) =>{
  const arryStringify = array.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));

  await redisStore.lpush(key, arryStringify) <--this takes almost 4s to complete
}
```

Comment: Redis only does around 80k requests per second so it very well might just be that long.
https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: got it thanks, will run bunch of tests